# PHPPowerPoint split cells vertically

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppowerpoint

I use PHPPowerPoint library to create a table in my presentation. Currently, I'm looking for a equivalent method of PP **"split cells"** option (as in picture below).

[image]

I would like to split a cell vertically - in two columns.

**Question**: How can I split a cell in two columns with PHPPowerPoint?

Comment: Issue opened : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/295